# credentials issue in Python while using AWS S3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

This error i am getting:

```
ERROR:boto:Unable to read instance data, giving up
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-62-476f799f9e0f>", line 2, in <module>
conn = boto.connect_s3()

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/__init__.py", line 141, in connect_s3
return S3Connection(aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/s3/connection.py", line 191, in __init__
validate_certs=validate_certs, profile_name=profile_name)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/connection.py", line 569, in __init__
host, config, self.provider, self._required_auth_capability())

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/auth.py", line 993, in get_auth_handler
'Check your credentials' % (len(names), str(names)))
```

> NoAuthHandlerFound: No handler was ready to authenticate. 1 handlers were checked. ['HmacAuthV1Handler'] Check your credentials

This error Message is coming while establishing connection with aws S3Connection.

I want to establish connection with AWS S3 and read CSV files.
please Help me out?
i am using Python 2.7.12

And Now i am  using this below code:

```
import boto
import time

from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection
conn = S3Connection('<aws access key>','<aws secret key>')
print conn


from boto.s3.connection import Location
print '\n'.join(i for i in dir(Location) if i[0].isupper())

conn.create_bucket('egp-shared-prod/egp-prod-c2c1/',
    location=Location.DEFAULT)
```

And, Its show Error:

```
 File "<ipython-input-69-4b49d719d4ca>", line 15, in <module>
conn.create_bucket('egp-shared-prod/egp-prod-c2c1/', location=Location.DEFAULT)

 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/s3/connection.py", line 616, in create_bucket
data=data)

 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/s3/connection.py", line 668, in make_request
retry_handler=retry_handler

 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/connection.py", line 1071, in make_request
retry_handler=retry_handler)

 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/connection.py", line 1030, in _mexe
raise ex

gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

Answer (score 3):

you can pass aws cridential access like:

```
#Connection with s3 :
s3= boto3.resource(
    service_name='s3',
    region_name='us-east-1',
    aws_secret_access_key='',     
    aws_access_key_id=''

    )
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and my testing has found that the error is related to your **bucket name** of `egp-shared-prod/egp-prod-c2c1/`.

The [Bucket Restrictions and Limitations](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/BucketRestrictions.html) documentation says:

> Bucket names can contain lowercase letters, numbers, and hyphens.

**Slashes** are not permitted. Also, they seem to be upsetting the `boto` code.

Comment: conn.create_bucket('mybuck', location='us-west-2')
now i am using this code for creating new Bucket.Still its showing error:--
S3ResponseError: S3ResponseError: 400 Bad Request
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>InvalidArgument</Code><Message>Authorization header is invalid -- one and only one ' ' (space) required</Message><ArgumentName>Authorization</ArgumentName><ArgumentValue>AWS &lt;aws access key&gt;:Yj6KZK1woMN6h+vtPlDJZrJ9OGQ=</ArgumentValue><RequestId>62DAB7149F211E2B</RequestId>

Comment: Please start a new Question and provide your current code and error message. If my Answer solved this current error, please mark it as Accepted. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Boto (the official AWS Python bindings) that you are using, expect you to save your AWS_ACCESS_KEY_id and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY in environment variables like so:

`export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID='AK123'
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY='abc123'`